# How to perform a non-blocking write to device?

Tags: c++, c, asynchronous, io, nonblocking

is it possible to make write(); function non-blocking without using threads?

```
short buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
int readcount;

while ((readcount = sounds[index].read(buffer, BUFFER_LEN)))
    write(audio_device, buffer, readcount * sizeof(short));
```

The sounds play, but it blocks program until it finished playing.

Comment: yes ,i think it possible making the write function without thread safe may cause different behaviour if at the same time other thread using same information......!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `fcntl` to set the `O_NONBLOCK` flag for the file will probably work, but you need to be prepared to deal with partial writes and `EWOULDBLOCK` errors.

Comment: I added O_NONBLOCK flag in, but that just distorts the sounds. Guess I will have to use threads then.

Comment: That's because you're ignoring the return value of `write`. If the file descriptor is non-blocking, `write` may return -1 with `errno` set to `EWOULDBLOCK`, in which case you have to wait and try the write again later. And of course `write` can always return fewer than the requested number of bytes you tried to write, in which case you have to keep the rest buffered and write it later.

Comment: Can you give me some sample code or where I should be reading, should I be using poll?

Comment: You can use `select` or `poll` to determine when it's okay to write most data, but this will block; that's the whole point. If you're already planning to `select` waiting for input, though, this could be the correct solution. On the other hand if you have more computation to do, you'll just have to keep retrying interspersed with the computation, or else use threads.